# Promise D3 js inside 'then'

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

Trying to understand the different steps to the Promise implementation for D3 js.

Have two input files and promise them all:

```
Promise.all([jsonFile, txtFile]).then(input)
```

The array has been consolidated into one individual input, which might be called as a one-parameter function like:

```
function input(data) {
 console.log(data[0])  // json
 console.log(data[1])  // txt
}
```

Imagine I want to implement the second function as a two-parameter with the two inputs like `function input(json, txt)`. What should happen in the `then()` statement to make the code do so?

Thanks

Comment: `.then` *never* calls the callback with more than one argument. You can only change your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement `input` function with two parameters:

```js
function input(json, txt) {
  // omitted
}
```

then you can use rest parameters [[more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)]:

```js
Promise.all([jsonFile, txtFile])
  .then((data) => input(...data))
```

or you can be more explicit:

```js
Promise.all([jsonFile, txtFile])
  .then(([json, txt]) => input(json, txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just about the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) behavior.
The documentation states that you have right expectations and the order of promises is preserved when they are resolved:

> Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

```js
const promises = [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve('some text')]
const processInputCallback = console.log

Promise.all(promises).then(processInputCallback)
```

Maybe the only thing to add here is that if any of promises gets rejected it will fail without waiting for all promises to get resolved.